# Incorrect geocode of state for sync tables

Tags: carto, geocoding

My sync table looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qrdti.png

[image]

What should be Lebanon, Kanasas is being geocoded to the lat/lon of Lebanon, Kentucky.

This has happened with other cities that have the same name in multiple states.

How can I ensure that that the state column is properly read for the sync table?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the automatic geocoding is just returning the result for the city that has more population in your case, probably.

When you geocode, you can select the column that contains the administrative region or even the country in which your cities are, but the automatic geocoding can only guess (at the moment) by city name and country. If the country is not explicitly written in another column, it uses some methods to guess in which countries are the cities (taking into account the whole information of the table).

This algorithm doesn't have into account still smaller administrative regions, so if there are cities with the same name inside a country they won't be guessed 100% correctly with the automatic guessing -- although you will be able to specify **manually** the administrative region in which they are, but this doesn't work for Sync tables as you cannot geocode the data afterwards.

Edit: Adding more info after talking through email:

If you're getting data through a Google Form, did you know that you don't even need a Sync Table? You can use a script that even geocodes your data in the Google side! More info [here](http://blog.cartodb.com/make-maps-from-data-you-collect-in-google-forms/).

If you're adding data directly in a Google Spreadsheet, have you considered triggering the Google geocoder in the table when there are editions on it? This will generate the coordinates that CartoDB will be able to understand.

There are even more things that you can do: if you're working just with data in one state, I can give you the subset of cities and coordinates we have for it in our geocoder and you can forget at all about geocoding: you can just get your map working by joining your data and geometries that will live in different tables with SQL.

I hope all these ideas help. We don't have that capability at this specific moment but we can help you (and we will be glad about it) to still be able to map your data.

Comment: So it sounds like I can't use sync tables for my project then (will have a lot of points in smaller cities). That's disappointing.

Comment: Are you using a google spreadsheet to sync? You can use the Google built-in geocoder for spreadsheets and sync that!

Comment: my data is coming from a json file on web-- trying to find a good solution of getting json to google sheets

Comment: Is it possible to have a column in google sheets for geom that can be set manually or left blank to let cartodb do the geocoding? the google sheets geocoder has daily limits :/

Comment: Columns called latitude and longitude (or lat and long/lon) will be geocoded automatically. Columns called the_geom that have a valid geometry inside (written in GeoJSON or WKT) will appear in the map too!